# How to download the files from a URL link and add it to destination folder in nsis?

Tags: nsis

I have a URL link say, www.xyz.com/download which contains a zip file. I want nsis script to download the file and add it to installer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to include the downloaded file into the installer, just do it before compiling the installer.

If you want to download the file when running the installer, you can use the [NSISdl plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSISdl_plug-in) that is already provided with NSIS.

There is also the [inetc plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in) that has a better proxy handling.